# Enable telnet banner on linux

Tags: telnet

I want to enable banner while users accessing my machine through telnet. I know how to achieve it through ssh http://servercomputing.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-add-ssh-login-banner.html

Comment: Which is it? Telnet or SSH? Make up your mind.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to edit

> /etc/issue.net

/etc/issue is the text that is displayed before any user is able to log on the system.

Or you can edit

> /etc/motd

Which displays after you log in

Comment: Hey, I tried it but message present in /etc/issue is not displayed while remote login through telnet.

Answer (score 1):

If your system telnet server is using pam login module, you can use following steps to enable telnet banner.

Add (uncomment) following lines in "**/etc/pam.d/login**"

**auth       required   pam_issue.so issue=/etc/issue noesc**

After this configuration, text from file "/etc/issue" is displayed as banner.

Make sure pam_issue.so library is present in your system library folders.